# What stops me from reading/writing further than the size of a shared memory? (System V IPC)

Tags: c, shared-memory, sysv-ipc

What I'm doing is:

`shmget(shm_key, shm_size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);` (and of course attach to it)

and I've already set the size to exactly 12 Bytes but when i try something like:

`sprintf(shm_ptr, "Imagine about 200-300 characters here\n");`

it seems to work normally with zero problems or warnings, and to check *that*, I tried to read it from a completely different process (i fork and exec the first one) and sure enough

`printf("%s", shm_ptr);`

prints the message that was in that segment, which is supposed to be 12 Bytes. Is System V IPC supposed to be like this, and there is no workaround for that issue? If so, why set a size in the first place?

Thanks for your time and answers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing stops you, but the spec does not guarantee any specific behavior for this case.

In practice, the actual size of a memory region will be round up to a system-specific page size. This makes it possible to access more memory than was requested, but there might be consequences. For example, memory sanitizers might treat this as an error.

This is true for all memory mapping, including those created with `mmap`.

Now, why do you need to access memory beyond requested region? If you need more memory, just request more. Having memory sanitizers not going crazy due to unexpected behavior is a very useful thing. Other than that, I don't think there are any consequences to this, at least I cannot come up with anything atm.

EDIT:
If you want to find access errors in your code, you can put a single "guard page" at the end of your memory block. Just allocate one additional page of memory and use `mprotect` to change its access rights to `PROT_NONE`. This way you will get segfault if you go beyond your mapping (but no more than 1 page).

Comment: From what I see from the other answer, too, I guess that was the reason I was getting no segfaults or errors or whatever; the size was rounded up to the nearest multiple of page size.

The reason I tried to force a mistake here was for future error-proofing myself, so if I did a mistake and tried to write/read outside of the available space I would get an error which would let me know pretty quick what my mistake was.

Comment: @AngelinoMehmeti I see. Unfortunately, I doubt you will be able to see any errors unless you go further beyond the end of the page. `valgrind` does not detect those errors (at least currently). You can try to find those errors with guard page. I have added some information to the answer.

Comment: Well that answers it for me then. Thanks for the quick reply, I'm marking your answer as the accepted one :)

Answer (score 1):

The [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) hardware is fixing the page size, so your virtual address space is organized in pages of 4Kbytes.

Any virtual address segment (even the one from SysV IPCMEM) is a multiple of that page size. Use [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) with  `PAGESIZE` or [getpagesize(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html) to get it.

(and Linux has also "huge pages" e.g. of 1Mbytes on x86).

BTW, read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and consider using `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/1234/maps` for the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) of pid 1234 to query the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of that process ....

PS. Prefer using [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html).

Comment: Oh I see, so the appropriate way to set the size is in multiples of page sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stops you from trying to use addresses outside of the region. But nothing protects you from possible consequences either.

It might just behave as though the region was larger. It might segfault (or whatever the equivalent is on your platform). It might overwrite random heap memory, causing your program to misbehave in unpredictable ways. It might do *anything*.

C does not provide a guardian who guarantees you are playing by the rules. Guardians are expensive and if you want one, you will have to pay for it yourself (by writing the guard code, and executing it as and when necessary).

Comment: Well, to be honest I was trying to get a segfault or something, just like when trying to access an out of bounds area of a pointer. If that happened I would know that when I do something wrong with my code there is a possibility that I get segfault, which narrows down the possible lines of codes that I've done a mistake at.

But from what I see from the other answers that's because the size is rounded up to the nearest multiple of page size, which makes sense why I get no errors/warnings etc.

Comment: Yes, the most likely implementation is that the shared memory will be placed at the beginning f a page, but there are no guarantees. It might be placed at the end or the middle. Also, there is no definite "page size" -- it s hardware-dependent.

Comment: And if you do manage to access the next page, there is no guarantee that that page is unmapped; it might belong to another shared memory segment or even to malloc. So it might or might no segfault.

Comment: Interesting, I did not expect that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: This goes a bit further from the topic, but what happens if the shared memory segment is partly in one page and the rest in the next page? First of all, is that even possible? If it is, does this mean I will be able to read/write in both pages, guaranteed that I won't get any segfaults/errors etc. ?

Comment: It is certainly possible for a shared memory segment to be larger than a page, but I don't know of any library implementation which unnecessarily spreads a segment over one more page than is required. Posix doesn't prohibit such behaviour, though, so it is theoretically possible. It is also possible (again, theoretically) that the standard library needs a bit of memory for its own metadata, in which case it could overallocate a bit (as malloc does, for example).

Comment: In short, *there are no guarantees* if you break the rules. Which is what I said in the first place :-)

Comment: I was actually not talking about a shared memory segment that's larger than a page, but for a segment that happened to begin somewhere close to the end of a page and was big enough to finish somewhere in the next page. But what you said probably answers my the case of my question too.
So I can indeed access any page in which there is even one Byte of my shared memory segment? This is interesting and sounds like trouble from someone who is looking for some :P

Comment: As i said, I doubt that will happen but it would not be a violation of the standard. The reason a library might conceivably place a small shared segment in the middle of a page would be to make it more difficult to guess its address. (Or possibly to smear addresses around the cache.) I don't know of implementations which do that either, but it is conceivable.