# why does my c++ program not work when I trying to print an element of a vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

My c++ programs are not working when using vectors.
The code of my program is given below, I am able to
compile the file but when I try to run it just throws an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> a;
    a[0]= 10;

    std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;

    a[0]= a[0]*10+5;
    std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;
}
```

I have tried commenting the lines with vector and writing another program in the same file but as soon as I uncomment the vector lines it throws an error on running.

I using VScode and MINgw.

Comment: Because you access vector element out of bounds. Default `std::vector` constructor creates an empty vector.

Comment: You have an empty vector, you cannot access any elements in it because there are none.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491286/how-reserve-in-stdvector-works-accessing-vector-with

Comment: Or initialize your vector first... e.g. `std::vector<int> values{10,20,30};` after that it is safe to access elements [0], [1] and [2]. Lookup vector's constructor documentation here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: `std::vector<int> a` creates `a` with zero elements.  Accessing `a[0]` therefore gives undefined behaviour.   You need to resize `a` to be (at least) `1` before using `a[0]`  (e.g. `a.resize(1)` before the first usage of `a[0]`.   More generally, rather than resorting to guesswork (and guessing wrong about how things work, as you have) try reading documentation for `std::vector` or a decent tutorial

Comment: BTW: you can change the vector to `std::map<int, int>` and it will work since map contract items when first accessed.

Comment: @SHR which is imo one of the few design flaws in the standard library ;) And it distracts from what OP is asking about.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242)

Comment: @OP `a[0]= 10;` -- Change that to `a.at(0) = 10;`.  What error do you get now?  [Do you understand what that error is telling you?](https://godbolt.org/z/1b8zj41G4)

Comment: Read this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub - including all the very nice linked articles at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
std::vector<int> a;
```

creates an empty vector without any element.

According to cppreference:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

```
a[0]= 10;
```

returns a reference to the element at a specified location - 0. No bounds checking is performed.

It does not mean: "Create element at position 0 and assign 10" - it assumes you have already created an element and saved new value to it"

What you want to do is:

```
std::vector<int> a; // create empty vector
a.push_back(10);    // add new value to vector
```

or alternatively

```
std::vector<int> a (1); //Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T (0 in our case)

std::cout << a[0] << std::endl; // It should return 0

a[0] = 10; 

std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;// It should return 10 now
```